# what is Json Format of wp_posts in api of wordpress?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, api

i want to get the post_content from wp_posts table in wordpress from an api ,

i am using utf8 encoding format , when i get the output from json api , the

field that i want is like this :

```
"post_title":"\u0631\u0627\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0646"
```

and my post_title is in persian language ,i want to turn this code to its

origin to get in persian .

**how can i turn this formated text into my language in android studio ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , Since again Nobody helped me , I found my answer Yohooooooooooooooo ....

the answer is simple ,

in API just replace this :

```
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

with this

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/iu", function($m){return iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U'.$m[1])));}, json_encode($myarrauy));
```

i am sure this is work for anyone .

Comment: The community's responsibility for helping you is limited by the ways and means of you actually forming a question. Your sarcastic  response will not help you moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress (as far as I know) still uses serialized data. You need to unserialize:

```
unserialize($mydata);
```

Comment: Great news! You can help the community by posting your solution here for others.